# Magento 2 how to find corresponding .less file?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

How can I find out the .less file to change the style for some element ?

It just shows styles-m.css or styles-l.css

Answer (score 1):

I find the easiest way is to search for the class you need to edit, after a while you will learn/remember where certain styling is usually implemented.

**Example**

For example let's say you want to change the top bar in the Luma theme.

[image]

If you inspect element in your browser you'll see the markup looks like this:

```
<div class="panel wrapper">
   ...
</div>
```

So if we use our editor to search for .panel.wrapper we get the following results:

[image]

If the files returned are in your own theme then you can edit them directly, if not then you'll need to create the relevant file in your own theme. See the [official docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-themes.html) for more info on this.

**Notes**

If you have Blank or Luma as a parent a lot of changes can be made by changing variables, for an example of how to do that see [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-practice.html)

Comment: ok so there is no, mechanism to map CSS to LESS files. in magento2

Comment: Yep, there are a few methods. I presumed you already knew about these - apologies. You can either set Magento 2 to client side so the browser will compile the Less, use Grunt, or create your own method. More info on the processing of Less can be read here - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html

Comment: I have tried grunt but when i run the command `grunt clear:luma` it just  open the grunt.js  file on magento installation directory in default editor

Comment: Have you tried client-side compilation? Login to the admin and navigate to stores > config > advanced > developer I think it is. Then set front-end workflow to client-side. This should then allow you to work without having to worry about compilation, although you will get an unstyled page for a second or two.